How can i solve this Error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"
I have built a web application in Laravel 8+, locally this application has no issue. After deploying on the Plesk Server (Shared Hosting, Windows Server) having a database connection error.
What I have tried

Connection details:

DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
#DB_HOST=localhost -- also tried
#DB_HOST=localhost\MSSQLSERVER2017 -- also tried
#DB_HOST=.\MSSQLSERVER2017 -- also tried
#DB_HOST=127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER2017 -- also tried
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=serverDbName
DB_USERNAME=serverDbUserName
DB_PASSWORD=serverDbPassword


My database config

'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],


The error looked like

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection 
could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select * from 
[table_name] where [status] = 1)


So does the Plesk-based hosting server actually have SQL Server installed, enabled and running?

Yes, I have created a database also.

What version and edition of Microsoft SQL Server is it? For example, most Express editions don't have the TCP/IP server protocol enabled by default and, even when they do, they're usually listening on a dynamically assigned port that is not tcp/1433.

Do you also have firewall rules permitting access to the port that the SQL Server instance is listening on?

Please don't dump tags in the title, and use a meaningful title as well; the error message is *not" a good title. See [ask].

I have deployed the application on a cloud server. I have no direct access on the server PC.
